# add a pdf a file my latex project

Tags: graphics

for my college project i want to add image in my latex file. so what iam done is i just converted my images into pdf and save it in the same folder having my project dvi file.
this is the code which i am trying to add image

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=15cm,height=10cm]

{figure1.pdf}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
```

but result is not showing and no error showing only showing the image name like figure1.pdf.
what is the wrong in this code, any one please help me i need to submit it next day..thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please remove the empty line (the paragraph break). Try with `\includegraphics[options]{figure1.pdf}`.

Comment: @TeXnician ya i removed empty space but still no image showing

Comment: iam using only this packeges "\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}"

Comment: Then please make your example compilable by adding the required packages, the documentclass and the document environment.

Comment: Wait a minute: You don't use `graphicx`? You should for including graphics.

Comment: ok i will try with graphicx

Comment: i added graphicx but stiil not working

Comment: Then please do as I suggested and add an example we can test.

Comment: meaning are you need complete file?

Comment: No, as I mentioned a minimal, but compilable example. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that.

Comment: If you have a .dvi file, does that mean you are compiling with latex and not pdflatex? In this case you need your images as eps files and not pdf.